# Backing up Wordpress Multisite

Tags: database, wordpress, mysql-backup

I have two question:

1. How many sites allow a Wordpress **Multisite** installation.
2. Probably it is a stupid question but, Is it possible to backup a specific **Sub-domain** in the multisite installation or you have to backup everything.

Answer (score 2):

The first part of your question doesn't make sense. How many sites allow a Multisite installation? How many web hosts you mean? If so, who knows? Several thousand and there's no way to keep track.

The second part of your question, Can I back up only one of the sub domains.... no. At least not in any meaningful way. Multisite shares the same database across all sites. I guess you might be able to do some sort of pattern searching in the database to do a backup on everything, but it's such a narrow use case I'd be surprised if anyone bothered, and I'd be even more surprised if it was actually reliable. Keep in mind: multisite is one database, multiple subdomains. Some info, wp_users, wp_user_meta, etc are going to be needed in each of these little mini-sites, and the pattern matching you'd have to write to only keep users for your own site would be, to put it mildly, a pain in the butt. You're better off just backing up everything. Exclude media files if you need to, but otherwise just back up the whole thing.

Comment: This is actually not entirely true...you can't make a full backup but you can export the posts as in a normal Wordpress from Settings->Export

Comment: Good point, good catch. If you just need the posts, that will work.

Answer (score 1):

First part of your question is not entirely clear, but you probably mean somehting along the lines is there a limit of sites which you can create in WPMU. The limit is your server...If you have powerful and well configured server you can have hundreds of sites without a problem(don't have an exact number though)

The only way to export a single site I can think of is by Going in Tools->Export and export the posts and settings as in a normal Wordpress, but you'll have to backup the uploaded files manually